# Move an object from one Activity to a Service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I need to move an object from an activity to a service. This is my attempt at the Activity side.

```
      Waveform waveform = new Waveform();
      Intent intent = new Intent(this, StimulationService.class);
      Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
      bundle.putParcelable("test", (Parcelable) waveform);
      intent.putExtras(bundle);
      startService(intent);
```

I have placed this code in the onStart() function in the service.

```
        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        if(bundle!=null)
        mWaveform = bundle.getParcelable(waveform);
```

I'm getting errors for the function "getIntent" and "waveform" inside the getParcelable().
Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Services don't have a `getIntent` method. Instead the intent is passed in as an argument to the `onStart` method. So you should use that parameter instead.
2. The `getParcelable` method takes a `String`, which in the case of your test code, should be `"test"`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to place an object into a `Bundle` you need to make that objects `Class` implement [`Parcelable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html). Here you can see how to use `Parcelable` [Android Parcelable Example](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/06/android-parcelable-example.html).

Then on your `onStart (Intent intent, int startId)` method you get the object from the `Intent` :

```
  public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        Wafeform waveform=intent.getExtras().getParcelable("test");
  }
```